# Ember-CLI: Fix for "'Ember' is not defined"?

Tags: ember.js, jslint, ember-cli

When using Ember-CLI and running ember server, I get the following error from JSLint:

```
[app_path]/filename.js: line 1, col 16, 'Ember' is not defined.
```

Adding `import Ember from 'ember';` fixes this.

Is this the official way to go now on all my files?  The documentation does not mention this change yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**

From Stephan Penner:

> We explicitly left it [Ember] out [of the .jshintrc file], please import ember instead.
>
> We plan on exposing more and more of ember as es6, someday this will
>   allow the tooling to remove parts of ember you are not using.
>   Resulting in smaller builds.

Still, until that date it's probably going to save you a lot of hassle to put it in `.jshintrc`.

**OUTDATED ANSWER**

In your `.jshintrc` file (or`tests/.jshintrc`), add anything in the global namespace you don't want to have to define in each module to the predef object. For example:

```
{
  "predef": {
    "document": true,
    "window": true,
    "SprintStatusENV": true,
    "Ember": true, // Added
    "$": true, // ADDED
    "Modernizr": true // ADDED
  },
  "browser" : true,
  "boss" : true,
  "curly": true,
  "debug": false,
  "devel": true,
  "eqeqeq": true,
  "evil": true,
  "forin": false,
  "immed": false,
  "laxbreak": false,
  "newcap": true,
  "noarg": true,
  "noempty": false,
  "nonew": false,
  "nomen": false,
  "onevar": false,
  "plusplus": false,
  "regexp": false,
  "undef": true,
  "sub": true,
  "strict": false,
  "white": false,
  "eqnull": true,
  "esnext": true,
  "unused": true
}
```

In this example, I define Ember (could also define Em), jQuery using '$' and Modernizr. This will stop the jshint error messages appearing in the terminal.

This is per the [ember-cli docs](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#using-modules):

> "If you want to use external libraries that write to a global namespace
>   (e.g. moment.js), you need to add those to the predef section of your
>   project’s .jshintrc file and set its value to true. If you use the lib
>   in tests, need to add it to your tests/.jshintrc file, too."

Comment: This is good to know... I wonder why 'Ember' is left out by default though?  It seems like one would need to use it a lot in an *Ember* app... no?

Comment: we explicitly left it out, please import ember instead.

Comment: @StefanPenner - thanks for the feedback. Can you expand on the reasoning? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @DuncanWalker we plan on exposing more and more of ember as es6, someday this will allow the tooling to remove parts of ember you are not using. Resulting in smaller builds.

Comment: also, this answer is not correct. This have been explicitly removed from jshint to encourage better practices..

Comment: I just upgraded an addon app from 0.1.2 to 0.1.15 and cannot get rid of this 'Ember' is not defined when running tests, I have "import Ember from 'ember';" at the top of start-app

Answer (score 6):

Expressly importing the Ember modules seems to be the official way now. The [Ember documentation](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/) under [Using Modules & the Resolver](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#using-modules) now says that you must expressly `import Ember` when you want to use Ember and `import DS` for Ember Data.

I've been searching for the reason and haven't found anything yet, but I'm presuming it's to make dependencies explicit and to make it possible to create plain old JavaScript object files.

Comment: "make it possible to create plain old JavaScript object files" -- that might be what I have been doing... also it looks like that addition to the documentation was added only a week ago, which is why i didn't notice it until now.  THanks!

Comment: I just found the new docs this morning. I was searching for the answer myself when I found your question, so I thought I'd answer.