# EmberCLI app errors when using fixtures

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I usually use Rails for my Ember apps. However this time we opted to decouple the API from the Ember app, and as such I'm trying EmberCLI. So far it's lovely to setup and use. However when using attempting to use fixtures it doesn't load the data.

As listed in [this post](http://edgycircle.com/blog/2014-using-fixtures-in-combination-with-ember-cli/) I am using `reopenClass` when declaring the fixtures.

If I do not override the model, it does not error but the Ember inspector also shows no data was loaded. If I override my file with:

```
// routes/campaigns/index.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('campaign');
  }
});
```

And visit the `/campaigns` path then I get the error I get the error `Error while loading route: undefined`.

From [what I can find](https://github.com/firebase/emberFire/issues/39) this seems to happen when Ember cannot find the data.

My router and model with obvious items like `export default` excluded:

```
// app/router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('campaigns', function() {
  });
});

// models/campaign.js
var Campaign = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

Campaign.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Campaign #1" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Campaign #2" }
  ]
});
```

I have tested the same setup in a Rails app I just made, and it works perfectly. I'd love any insight people could give, as EmberCLI seems lightweight and worth the effort.

**Edit:** Adding my `app.js` file to answer question about whether I included `DS.FixtureAdapter`:

```
// Import statements

Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;

var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: 'nala', // TODO: loaded via config
  Resolver: Resolver
});

loadInitializers(App, 'nala');

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter({});

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you have `export default DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});` in `adapters/application.js`?

Comment: @DuncanWalker adding that line to `adapters/application.js` pulls in the data now. I was following from [Ember's example](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-fixture-adapter/), but it seems the EmberCLI docs could use some added notes. If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up your application adapter located at the filepath `adapters/application.js` as follows:

```
export default DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
```

See the first paragraph under [ember-cli Naming Conventions](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/). N.B. you won't need to import DS or Ember if you're using ember-cli and have them [listed in your .jshintrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312362/ember-cli-fix-for-ember-is-not-defined/24443160#24443160).